# NoClassDefFoundError ANRManagerProxy

Tags: java, android, android-anr-dialog

I am using Crashlytics to keep track of crashes on an app i published on Play Store. A large number of crashes are due to the `NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.ANRManagerProxy` error. I have no idea what this error means or how to solve it. This is the full log.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.ANRManagerProxy
   at android.app.ANRManagerNative.asInterface(ANRManagerNative.java:30)
   at android.app.ANRManagerNative$1.create(ANRManagerNative.java:94)
   at android.app.ANRManagerNative$1.create(ANRManagerNative.java:88)
   at android.util.Singleton.get(Singleton.java:34)
   at android.app.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(ANRManagerNative.java:37)
   at android.os.MessageLogger.dump(MessageLogger.java:253)
   at android.app.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:38)
   at     android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1176)
   at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:609)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
```

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: This means that the application is not able to find the class `ANRManagerProxy`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289641/noclassdeffounderror-android-app-anrmanagerproxy

Comment: How can i solve the error. Because it accounts for the largest number of crashes with my users.

Comment: ANR --> Application not responding
Do not worry about this NoClassDefFoundError, worry about what caused this ANR in first place (memory leak or just not enough hardware to support your App)

Comment: So should i be worried about a message on the log that says, 'application is doing too much work on main thread'?